# Coprime numbers and intersection of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that the intersection of two subgroups is {identity element} if their orders are coprime (proof via Lagrange's Theorem). But can we say: if the intersection of two finite subgroups is {identity element}, then their orders are coprime? I think yes, I tried to prove the contrary, but I stucked. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: This is clearly false. Just look at $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true. Consider for example $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. There are three proper nontrivial subgroups of the same order that all intersect trivially pairwise.

Comment: Sorry, probably, I made a mistake in the question: if the intersection of two finite subgroups is {identity element}, then their orders are coprime? Is it still incorrect?

Comment: @Young This example covers that. The orders of the three subgroups are actually the same, so certainly not coprime, and the intersection of any two of them is just the identity.